# Disable time and tags in fluentd stdout output plugin

Tags: plugins, kubernetes, fluentd

Remove time and tag from fluentd output plugin stdout with json

Fluentd's output plugin produces output like:

2017-11-28 11:43:13.814351757 +0900 tag: {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}

So timestamp and tag are before the json. How can I remove these fields - I only like to have the json output

```
<match pattern>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

expected output:
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"}

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue and have been unsuccessful in addressing the issue

Comment: Hi @tommes did you manage solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the json format type which by default doesn't includes time and tag in output:

```
<match pattern>
  @type stdout
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try filters?

```
<filter pattern>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
      ${tag}
  </record>
</filter>
```

Comment: no still the same behaviour. I hope there is a way to change the pattern of the output plugin, by default json format does not add these fields but the stdout plugin does referring to the manual.

Comment: Seems like the opposite what the OP was asking, but exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.